# Format the date using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The flickr api provides a posted date as unix timestamp one: "`The posted date is always passed around as a unix timestamp, which is an unsigned integer specifying the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 GMT.`"

For example, here is the date '`1100897479`'. How do I format it using Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 206):

Once you have parsed the timestamp string and have a time object (see other answers for details), you can use [Time.to_formatted_s](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_formatted_s) from Rails. It has several formats built in that you can specify with symbols.

Quote:

```
time = Time.now                     # => Thu Jan 18 06:10:17 CST 2007

time.to_formatted_s(:time)          # => "06:10"
time.to_s(:time)                    # => "06:10"

time.to_formatted_s(:db)            # => "2007-01-18 06:10:17"
time.to_formatted_s(:number)        # => "20070118061017"
time.to_formatted_s(:short)         # => "18 Jan 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:long)          # => "January 18, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  # => "January 18th, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)        # => "Thu, 18 Jan 2007 06:10:17 -0600"
```

(Time.to_s is an alias)

You can also define your own formats - usually in an initializer (Thanks to [Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) for pointing this out). This is how it's done:

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_ordinal] = lambda { |time| time.strftime("%B #{time.day.ordinalize}") }
```

Comment: +1; the easiest solution once there's a date, especially if one of the existing formats works.

Comment: Yep, via a map in initializers.

Comment: Note that Time::DATE_FORMATS does not get passed through to rails Date objects. For Date objects use Date::DATE_FORMATS

Comment: You can also now use I18n. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Comment: When a language is written by a Japanese developer, no wonder the dates are so non-US friendly :)

Comment: Is there a list of the variables you can use here? The only ones you have are %B and %Y

Comment: A couple of notes on this. 1) You can run Time::DATE_FORMATS and Date::DATE_FORMATS from the console to see the available formats  (e.g., :short, :long, etc) and how they are defined. 2) Using :default, will set a default format that will be automatically applied. So it's not uncommon to place Time:: DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "....your custom format here..." within a time_formats.rb initializer. Finally, @MarkKramer you can see a list of accepted date format directives by looking up strftime. Ruby simply uses the standard Unix date format syntax.

Answer (score 54):

Here's my go at answering this,

so first you will need to convert the timestamp to an actual Ruby Date/Time. If you receive it just as a string or int from facebook, you will need to do something like this:

```
my_date = Time.at(timestamp_from_facebook.to_i)
```

OK, so now assuming you already have your date object...

**[to_formatted_s](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_formatted_s)** is a handy Ruby function that turns dates into formatted strings.

Here are some examples of its usage:

```
time = Time.now                     # => Thu Jan 18 06:10:17 CST 2007    

time.to_formatted_s(:time)          # => "06:10"
time.to_s(:time)                    # => "06:10"    

time.to_formatted_s(:db)            # => "2007-01-18 06:10:17"
time.to_formatted_s(:number)        # => "20070118061017"
time.to_formatted_s(:short)         # => "18 Jan 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:long)          # => "January 18, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)  # => "January 18th, 2007 06:10"
time.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)        # => "Thu, 18 Jan 2007 06:10:17 -0600"
```

As you can see: **:db, :number, :short** ... are custom date formats.

To add your own custom format, you can create this file: **config/initializers/time_formats.rb** and add your own formats there, for example here's one:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:month_day_comma_year] = "%B %e, %Y" # January 28, 2015
```

Where **:month_day_comma_year** is your format's name (you can change this to anything you want), and where **%B %e, %Y** is unix date format.

Here's a quick cheatsheet on unix date syntax, so you can quickly setup your custom format:

```
From http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime    

  %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %e - Day of the month without leading 0 (1..31) 
  %g - Year in YY (00-99)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character    

   t = Time.now
   t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 04/09/2003"
   t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:56AM"
```

Hope this helped you.
I've also made a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/eduwass/4ee6b9de3c5013cbd3af) of this little guide, in case anyone prefers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10586543)

Comment: Hi @MihaiCaracostea , re-did my answer following your advice, thanks :)

Comment: Is it not working for me. I added the date format in the initializers folder. Here is how im using it in the view `@question.created_at.to_formatted_s(:month_day_comma_year)` but I get `#2019-07-27 03:27:41 UTC`

Comment: what about `DateTime` can it also use this?

Answer (score 28):

[Easiest is to use `strftime` (docs)](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Time/strftime).

If it's for use on the view side, better to wrap it in a helper, though.

Comment: I did't figure out how to use it. Can you give me a tiny example please?

Comment: my_date_variable.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: strftime is not DRY. Please don't scatter strftime all over your projects. At least you mentioned a helper but `config/initializers/time_formats.rb` is more idiomatic for Rails.

Comment: @PhilT As I mentioned in my comment on the highest-voted answer, which was rolled in to said answer.

Answer (score 17):

@CMW's answer is bang on the money. I've added this answer as an example of how to configure an initializer so that both Date and Time objects get the formatting

config/initializers/time_formats.rb

```
date_formats = {
  concise: '%d-%b-%Y' # 13-Jan-2014
}

Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge! date_formats
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge! date_formats
```

Also the following two commands will iterate through all the `DATE_FORMATS` in your current environment, and display today's date and time in each format:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.keys.each{|k| puts [k,Date.today.to_formatted_s(k)].join(':- ')}
Time::DATE_FORMATS.keys.each{|k| puts [k,Time.now.to_formatted_s(k)].join(':- ')}
```

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [`localize`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/svenfuchs/i18n/master/I18n/Backend/Base:localize), or `l`

eg:

```
l Time.at(1100897479)
```

Comment: This is the best solution, because the format can vary per locale. You can also add as many custom formats as you wish: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Answer (score 6):

First you will need to convert the timestamp to an actual Ruby Date/Time.
If you receive it just as a string or int from facebook, you will need to do something like this:

```
my_date = Time.at(timestamp_from_facebook.to_i)
```

Then to format it nicely in the view, you can just use `to_s` (for the default formatting):

```
<%= my_date.to_s %>
```

Note that if you don't put `to_s`, it will still be called by default if you use it in a view or in a string e.g. the following will also call `to_s` on the date:

```
<%= "Here is a date: #{my_date}" %>
```

or if you want the date formatted in a specific way (eg using "d/m/Y") - you can use `strftime` as outlined in the other answer.

Comment: This code throws an error `puts  Time.at('1100897479')` -- can't convert String into an exact number (TypeError)

Comment: Ah, it's arriving as a string? ok so "to_i" it to make certain it's an int (example above edited to include this)

Answer (score 1):

Since the timestamps are seconds since the UNIX epoch, you can use [DateTime.strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) ("string parse time") with the correct specifier:

```
Date.strptime('1100897479', '%s')
#=> #<Date: 2004-11-19 ((2453329j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.strptime('1100897479', '%s').to_s
#=> "2004-11-19"
DateTime.strptime('1100897479', '%s')
#=> #<DateTime: 2004-11-19T20:51:19+00:00 ((2453329j,75079s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.strptime('1100897479', '%s').to_s
#=> "2004-11-19T20:51:19+00:00"
```

Note that you have to `require 'date'` for that to work, then you can call it either as `Date.strptime` (if you only care about the date)  or `DateTime.strptime` (if you want date and time). If you need different formatting, you can call [DateTime#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) (look at [strftime.net](http://strftime.net/) if you have a hard time with the format strings) on it or use one of the built-in methods like `rfc822`.