# How to display and save MMM-DD-YYYY format with datetimepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, date, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I use bootstrap3 `datetimepicker` in Rails 4 app.

The date is saved `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

When I edit the data with using `{format:'MMM-DD-YYYY'}`, the date doesn't display and save correctly.

```
database: `2016-03-26`
view: `Jan-03-0026`
```

How can I display and save the date as I expect?

**_xxx_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.label :departure_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:'MMM-DD-YYYY'});
    });
  </script>
```

Is this the only and best way to use the 3rd answer [Changes in the form are not saved to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405703/rails-simple-form-bootstrap-and-datepicker)?
I asked because this answer was posted 3 years ago.

This question is about date format, so not duplicate of `Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: design is not good`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: design is not good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229657/rails-4-x-bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-design-is-not-good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you display `MM-DD-YY` then use below code

```
<%= t.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>
```

For further instruction please see [this](https://hackhands.com/format-datetime-ruby/) Or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11097669/4172515)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @kings man. It would appreciated if you could give me how to apply it to my code. Although I tried some, it didn't work.

Comment: You just write `db_col_name`  for example `<%= db_col_name.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @kings man. It works with using '<%= f.text_field :departure_date, :value => (f.object.departure_date.strftime('%b/%d/%Y') if f.object.departure_date), class: 'form-control' %>'.